# Log File Output Doesn't Match Debugger

Tags: c#

C# in MS Visual Studio 2010.  I am writing output to a log file as part of some code verification.   The debugger shows the groups are getting the proper match, as does the Match output.  The only thing that is wrong is the output file and I don't know why.   Here is the output I get from the file, where readline is the input line, Match is the result of a Regex match and Slot/Port are the result of getting values from named groups in the Regex.  You can see from the log that the Regex Match matches the input line.  The debugger says the Named Groups are working.

```
readline is: fc1/1 is up
Match is: fc1/1 is
Slot and Port are: 1/1
readline is: fc1/3 is up
Match is: fc1/3 is
Slot and Port are: 1/1
```

Here is the code that does the match - there is some extra stuff I added just to make it easier to watch in the debugger.

```
if (RegexExtensions.TryMatch(out InterfaceMatch, trimmed, InterfaceMatchString))
                {
                    SlotNum = Convert.ToInt32(InterfaceMatch.Groups["slot"].Value);
                    PortNum = Convert.ToInt32(InterfaceMatch.Groups["port"].Value);
                    string slot = InterfaceMatch.Groups["slot"].Value;
                    string port = InterfaceMatch.Groups["port"].Value;
  // write the value of current incoming readline
                  CiscoDecodeVariables.swlog.WriteLine(String.Format("readline is: {0}", readline));
 // write the value of the current match
                  CiscoDecodeVariables.swlog.WriteLine(String.Format("Match is: {0}", InterfaceMatch.Value.ToString()));
                  string slotasstring = SlotNum.ToString();
                  string portasstring = PortNum.ToString();
   // here is the line that writes what the slot and port values are
               CiscoDecodeVariables.swlog.WriteLine(String.Format("Slot and Port are: {0}/{0}", slotasstring, portasstring));
                CiscoDecodeVariables.swlog.Flush();
                    //sw.Close();
                    currPort = ((PortModule)ModuleList[SlotNum]).FCPortList[PortNum - 1];
                }
```

Finally, here is the code for the StreamWriter.  I decleared a static class with a static variable so I can use the Streamwriter where I need to.

```
static public class CiscoDecodeVariables
{
    static public string LogFileOutPutPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + @"\\ciscodecodelog.txt";
    static public StreamWriter swlog = new StreamWriter(LogFileOutPutPath);

}
```

Adding the RegEx match pattern in question
    string InterfaceMatchString = @"fc(?\d+)/(?\d+) is";

Also, the RegexExtensions.TryMatch() is a static method that returns true for a successful match and sets the InterfaceMatch instance to the result.

Comment: So are you saying that if you stop on the line where you write out the match and put `InterfaceMatch.Value.ToString()` in the watch window that it comes out with something that isn't then written to the swlog as you'd expect? Because that is weird if so...

Comment: Yes.  The debugger looks good.  The 'currPort' line in the above assigns the current port to the correct port, that is the port in the Module List with the slot and port that matches what I parse out of the Regex.  The only thing I can think of is String.Format() is doing something with the slot and port values I feed it.

Comment: Please add the Regex expression and the input string(s).  Thanks!  Also, what types are SlotNum and PortNum?

Comment: Ok... the answer is that String.Format() is doing something.  I get the expected output with a StringBuilder - the slot and port values match what is in the debugger.   Now the question, what is String.Format() doing? Why does an int converted to a string matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem with your format string.

```
CiscoDecodeVariables.swlog.WriteLine(String.Format("Slot and Port are: {0}/{0}", slotasstring, portasstring));
```

"{0}/{0}" means that you'll get the result "slotasstring/slotasstring" rather than "slotasstring/portasstring".

Answer (score 2):

Your code:

```
"Slot and Port are: {0}/{0}"
```

Correct code:

```
"Slot and Port are: {0}/{1}"
```

Easy typo mistake it looks like. :)

And to clarify for those who may not understand the first line is explicitly putting the same thing in twice (the first of the followup parameters) whereas the second line is putting in the first paramters and then the second (via the {0} and {1}).

As an additional note `String.Format` takes any object and will call ToString on it if needed so there is no need to convert to strings first (though I understand you may have put those lines in purely for debug help). Also there is a `InterfaceMatch.Value.ToString()` where I believe that `Value` should already be a string.

Comment: One of the classics! Resharper will pick up these errors for you :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip on String.Format(). I didn't know it would run ToString() for me.  As for converting to strings first, yes that was just for debugging.  That way I don't have to dig through the RegEx match for the value (and just to verify that ToString() for an int does what I expect)